# Remove linebreak arrow and move last word to next line

Tags: text-editing, customize

When I write text in the emacs editor and the text reaches the right border of the program, emacs continues on the next line and puts an arrow on both sides of its borders. I want to know if its possible to remove these ugly arrows and modify emacs in a way, that the last word is put on the next line instead of the last letters. So it would quite more readable because no words are cut due to a linebreak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like Visual Line mode is what you want: `M-x visual-line-mode`

Comment: Does visual line do word wrapping by default?

Comment: @Malabarba I tested it out and it worked. I got the desired result. What do I have to do to make it permanent? I added (visual-line-mode), (visual-line-mode t) and (visual-line-mode 1) in the .emacs file but none of them worked. If this is a trivial problem I am sorry but I am new to emacs

Comment: Okay, I found the answer for permanent behaviour. Add (global-visual-line-mode t) to the .emacs file. Found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281581/how-to-word-wrap-in-emacs